# Rails - Get contents but only when url param is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a rails newb question. I have a `Contents` model that has a `content_type` attribute. I have a few different content_types that I would like to filter, passing the type through the URL like so: /contents?content_type=blog

I understand I can get the contents based on that parameter like so:

```
@contents = Content.where({:content_type => params[:content_type]})
```

But when the URL parameter is not present, it's not getting any contents. I would prefer that when a URL param isn't being passed, that all contents (regardless of type) would be retrieved. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define a scope, like this (inside your model)

```
class Content

  scope :by_content_type, lambda { |contenttype|
    where({:content_type => contenttype}) unless contenttype.blank? 
  }

end
```

and then you use this in your controller as follows:

```
@contents = Content.by_content_type(params[:content_type])
```

Comment: I'd suggest this instead: `contenttype.blank? ? scoped : where(content_type: contenttype)`

Comment: In my opinion a scope without the condition is by definition scoped, so that is not needed.

Comment: I've never changed an accepted answer on SO, but this is very cool, it keeps the controller slim.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if params[:content_type].blank?
  @contents = Content.scoped
else
  @contents = Content.where({:content_type => params[:content_type]})
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest `.scoped` rather than `.all` as then either branch will return a scope. In rails-3, `#all` returns a straightforward array.

Comment: Many thanks, did the trick. Also + 1, never heard of scoped, appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a reasonable pattern here using a series of chained scopes to narrow filters based on query params:

```
  @contents = Content.scoped # Start with no filter

  # Optionally narrow filter if filter param is present
  type = params[:content_type]
  @contents = @contents.where(:content_type => type) if type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@contents = Content.where({(:content_type => params[:content_type]} unless params[:content_type].blank?))
```

Comment: This will set @contents to nil, I think the poster was hoping he would get all Contents unless the filter param is specified.

Comment: Was hoping for something nice and clean like this, but like Winfield says it returns nil.

Comment: @Winfield: Nope, it either filters or returns the full (scoped) set. Pay attention to the parentheses.  I tested it and everything :-)